# Using a boolean function after where (SQL)?

Tags: sql, vba

I'm trying to use a function that results a boolean after in a where in a SQL statement.

What the function does is that it verifies if the selected date is within two const dates and results a boolean. I'm having problem with the SQL syntax

```
Sqlstring = "Select count() from [Orders].[Date]" & _ 
where " & Function([Orders].[Date]) = True & ""
```

I'm not sure if the sql statement is correct.

Edit here's the code:

```
public StartDate as String
public EndDate As string

Private Function GetOrdersNumbers() As Integer
Dim rsData As ADODB.RecordSet

Dim szConnect As String
Dim szSQL As String
Dim DataSource As String

DataSource = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\db.mdb"
szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEBD.4.0;" & _
"Data Source=" & DataSource & ";" & _
"user ID=admin;password=;"

szSQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Et_Journal Livraison Fournisseur] WHERE [Et_Journal Livraison Fournisseur].[Date] BETWEEN [@StartDate] And [@EndDate] "
Set rsData = New ADODB.RecordSet

rsData.Open szSQL, szConnect, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
If Not rsData.EOF Then
Range("A01").CopyFromRecordset RecordSet
GetOrdersNumbers = CInt(Range("A01").Value)
End If
End Function
```

Comment: The concatenation on the second line is wrong and should be `" where Function([Orders].[Date]) = True"`.  Make sure you leave a space before the where, otherwise you'll have `[Orders].[Date]where`

Comment: Why to use function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not provide information about database engine... Nevertheless

I'd suggest to use query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Orders
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN [@date1] AND [@date2]
```

where
**@date1** and **@date1** is a parameter

There's no reason to use function.

**[EDIT]**

Thank you for clarification. Have a look at below code:

```
Option Explicit


Sub Test()
Dim d1 As Date
Dim d2 As Date

d2 = DateSerial(2015, 1, 6)
d1 = DateAdd("MM", -3, d2)

MsgBox GetOrdersNumbers(d1, d2)

End Sub

Function GetOrdersNumbers(ByVal StartDate As Date, ByVal EndDate As Date) As Long
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection, oRst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sConnString As String, sQry As String
Dim retVal As Long

sConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEBD.4.0;" & _
            "Data Source=C:\Users\user\Desktop\db.mdb;" & _
            "user ID=admin;password=;"

Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
With oConn
    .ConnectionString = sConnString
    .Open
End With

sQry = "SELECT [Date] As MyDate" & vbCr & _
        "FROM [Et_Journal Livraison Fournisseur]" & vbCr & _
        "WHERE [Et_Journal Livraison Fournisseur].[Date] BETWEEN #" & StartDate & "# And #" & EndDate & "#"

Set rsData = New ADODB.Recordset

oRst.Open szSQL, oConn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

retVal = oRst.RecordCount

End If

Exit_GetOrdersNumbers:
    On Error Resume Next
    oRst.Close
    Set oRst = Nothing
    oConn.Close
    Set oConn = Nothing
    GetOrdersNumbers = retVal
    Exit Function

Err_GetOrdersNumbers:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, Err.Number
    Resume Exit_GetOrdersNumbers
End Function
```

Comment: [Be careful using the devil `BETWEEN`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

Comment: @PatrickHofman you can use VBA to connect to a host of different database engines.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, using VBA + ADODB you can access SQL server data ;)

Comment: @RubberDuck, Thank you for your valuable comments, especially the first one. I know about that, but it might be helpful to OP.